# Laravel custom password validation

Tags: php, html, validation, laravel, laravel-blade

Hi gladly I want to use a custom validation rule for my textfield:

```
{{Form::label('password', 'Wachtwoord: ', array('class' => 'col-xs-4'))}}
<div class="col-xs-2">{{ Form::password('password',  array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password')) }}</div>
```

And I already had followed the instructions on the following link: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

But I get stuck when I want to use my custom validation.. I think that I have done something wrong in my code.

Gladly I would like to use the validatePassword() method (in validation.php) for my password textfield.

Here is my UserController.php:

```
public function update($id)
{

    $user_old_data = User::find($id);

    $input_password = Input::get('password');

    Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
    {
        return new validation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });


    /*Validator::extend('validatePassword', function($input_passwords,$input_passwords){

    });*/

    /*$validator = Validator::make($data = $thisUser, User::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {

        if($user_old_data['email'] != $new_email){

            $email_exists = User::FindEmailOrFail2(Input::get('email') );    

            if($email_exists)
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        } 


        //maak message variabel aan in je user index view.
        return Redirect::to('user/users')->with('message', 'Update with new password succesfull');
    } */

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Here is my validation.php:

```
<?php
// app/validators/validation.php
 class validation extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator
 {

      public function validateFoo($attribute, $value, $parameters){

        //return $value == 'foo';
         echo "this is the: " . $value;
      }
      //{4,} will match strings of length 4 or more.
      protected function validatePassword( $attribute, $value ) {
            return (bool) preg_match('/^[a-z]{4,}+$/', $value);
            die('test');
        }



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code reflects the scope of your project you may not need a custom validator at all. You can use `pattern:/^[a-z]{4,}$/` as one of your `$rules` in your User model.

You can see examples in Laravel's documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#basic-usage

The pattern you used : `/^[a-z]{4,}+$/` can be interpreted as "a string beginning with at least 4 characters matching lowercase a through z and a plus sign at the end of the string". Removing the plus sign (which regex is interpreting literally because of the quantifier before it) should make this work properly.

Remember to `artisan optimize` after you make changes to make sure the compiled.php is recompiled.

Comment: Pattern didn't work, but the following does works: 'password'=>'regex:/^[a-z]{4,}+$/' But it doesn't work completely good. Because when I type 'asdf' it should be a valid input. But I keep getting the message: The password format is invalid. Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you remove all other custom validation?

Comment: That plus sign isn't valid. The olus signs says '1 or more' and just before that you are saying 'at least 4'.

Comment: Edited for clarity. It may now answer you question.